# Spring boot controller test returns 200 when expected is 404

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

I am trying to test the controller layer. In this case to find a customer by id.
I have a passing test which works fine and returns `200` status code.
Now, I want a failing test case scene. So when I get  `/customers/1` the test should fail and return a `404`, but it is returning `200`.
Using Junit5, Spring-boot:2.5.3

```
@WebMvcTest
public class CustomerControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("GET /customers/1 -Failure")
    void findCustomerByIdShouldReturn_404() throws Exception {
        when(customerService.findById(1L)).thenReturn(Optional.empty());

        RequestBuilder requestBuilder= MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/customers/{id}",1);

        mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder)
                .andExpect(status().isNotFound()).andReturn();
    }
}
```

Error:

```
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /customers/1
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = []
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.prabhakar.customer.controller.CustomerController
           Method = com.prabhakar.customer.controller.CustomerController#findCustomerById(Long)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json"]
     Content type = application/json
             Body = null
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<404> but was:<200>
Expected :404
Actual   :200
```

Here is my controller and service class.

```
@RestController
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @GetMapping(path = "/customers/{id}")
    public Optional<Customer> findCustomerById(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
        return customerService.findById(id);
    }
}



@Service
public class CustomerService {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    
    public Optional<Customer> findById(Long id) {
        return customerRepository.findById(id);
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't see anything in your controller that returns a 404 response when the entity is not found?

Comment: If are expecting a exception to be raised when no customer is returned. Return a Customer object rather optional of it from controller. Also handle the exception with @exceptionalHandler to send 404 status. Guess, your code will respond with a empty JSON when no customer is found, rather a 404 on exception.

Comment: Why return `Optional<>` from the controller?  What does the JSON for that look like?  Is there a custom converter?

Comment: ```[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Alex"
    }
]``` Json looks like this. I have returned a Optional<> from service and if it is not present returned a Response entity from controller with 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller does not have the logic that you expect to test. Here is how your controller should be implemented to behave the way you want it to

```
@RestController
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @GetMapping(path = "/customers/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> findCustomerById(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
        Optional<Customer> optCust = customerService.findById(id);
        if (optCust.isPresent()){
            return ResponseEntity.ok(optCust.get());
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build()
        }
    }
}
```